# how to split the element of my list and convert it to dictionary and print the key?

Tags: python-3.7

How to convert my list in this `format( [(9.0, 'artificial intelligent branch'), (4.0, 'soft computing'), (4.0, 'six branches')]` to dictionary like  this `[(9.0: 'artificial intelligent branch'), (4.0: 'soft computing'), (4.0: 'six branches')]` and how to print the key of dictionary?

Comment: The dictionary format you mentioned you wish to get as an output is wrong. Dicts in Python looks like this `{key1: value1, key2: value,...}`. Also your input list has an extra brace in front. You should edit your question to make it clear for others to answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating the dictionary

Here is the code for creating the dictionary

```py
lst = [(9.0, 'artificial intelligent branch'), (4.0, 'soft computing'), (4.0, 'six branches')]
dic = {key: value for key, value in lst}
```

This, however, is not optimal. If we now print `lst`, we get

```
{9.0: 'artificial intelligent branch', 4.0: 'six branches'}
```

This is because we have two values of `4.0`, which overwrite each other. A solution to this might be to simple swap the keys and values:

```py
lst = [(9.0, 'artificial intelligent branch'), (4.0, 'soft computing'), (4.0, 'six branches')]
dic = {key: value for value, key in lst}
```

We then get

```
{'artificial intelligent branch': 9.0,
 'soft computing': 4.0,
 'six branches': 4.0}
```

Which might be better, depending on your needs.

Another solution might be

```
dic = {}
for key, value in lst:
    if key in dic:
        dic[key].append(value)
    else:
        dic[key] = [value]
```

This creates a list for each key, giving the result

```
{9.0: ['artificial intelligent branch'],
 4.0: ['soft computing', 'six branches']}
```

This can be simplified a bit:

```py
for key, value in a:
    b[key] = b.get(key, []) + [value]
```

We here always assign the key to a new value, but we set the new value to be the list that was already there pluss the list of the new value. We use the `.get` method of a dictionary to provide a default value, in case `b[key]` doesn't exist.

### Iterating dictionary

Iterating through a dictionary can be done like this

```py
for key, value in dic.items().
    print(key, value)

# Or
for key in dic.keys():
    print(key)

# Or
for value in dic.values():
    print(value)
```